# SPARQL Getting Instances of a certain class

Tags: sparql

I have 2 questions regarding Sparql:

1. I have a class and I'm trying to get all instances of a certain class. I'm using Protege. There are 2 instances for the 'Actor' class. How can I write a sparql query to extract only these two values?
2. Additional to question 1, how can I match only one value. For example how do I modify Question 1's query to match == "Third Party API"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what did you try so far? this is not a "please provide me the query platform" - the question is rather trival, any SPARQL tutorial should help you already. I mean, the first is a sinple `SELECT` query with a single triple pattern and predicate and object given. I'm sure this is easy for you

Comment: I can tell you why nobody can provide the SPARQL query ... because you didn't provide the data. RDF is made of URIs and literals, without showing the URIs of your class nobody here can provide the final query. Or shall people guess the URIs? I could by the way also aks you the same, why not using a search engine of your choice for "SPARQL get all instances of a class" - pretty sure there would be some hits.

Comment: anyways, here the query for 1): `SELECT ?s WHERE {?s a <THE_CLASS_URI_HERE> }` - done.

Comment: 2) I don't get. do you want to get the opposite, i.e. all classes and instance belongs to? If so, it would be quite similar, just provide the subject instead of the objects: `SELECT ?cls WHERE {<THE_INDIVIDUAL_URI_HERE> a ?cls }` - if this is not what you want, please clarify a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. I had tried what you had written but for whatever reason Protege always returns data empty for the given query even when I tried with other ontologies. Isn't instances should be returned in your first query?